# Purpose of including 'r' in the open() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the difference between:

```
with open('PHANTOM_PAIN_SPOILERS.txt') as temp:
    print(temp.read())
```

...and:

```
with open('PHANTOM_PAIN_SPOILERS.txt','r') as temp:
    print(temp.read())
```

To my understanding, the second argument `'r'` for the `open()` is essentially telling the system to read the file after opening it, which seems to me that it should make `.read()` redundant but if I attempt to print temp `print(temp)` in the second example, I end up with something similar to: `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='PHANTOM_PAIN_SPOILERS.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>`

So what was the point of specifying 'r' in the first place if it doesn't seem to do anything in these instances?

Comment: There is no difference, the default is `r`.

Comment: There are [different ways](http://www.endmemo.com/program/python/open.php) to tell python to open a file. Reading, `r`, is one way, but you can also write to the file with `w` (etc).

Comment: The default is "r" in `open`. You can skip that. Both of them would return a file object. You will have to use `read()` for reading the file.

Comment: refer to the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: So why do people even bother specifying the second argument as solely 'r' if it is what the function already does by default? I assumed it was a necessary step to include it.

Comment: @user155876 I prefer to put it for readability.. others might find it very readable even without supplying it. In this case, I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: @user155876 it helps other people understand what you're doing, for one. Not everyone necessarily knows that without an argument, read mode is implied.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open the options are listed in here aswell..

Comment: It just seems a little arbitrary to include 'r' in the open() function solely on the basis that not everyone knows that the function already does that by default. I understand that legibility and conveying your code clearly is important but in this case, wouldn't most people already know that the open() function reads by default when they first learn to use it unless they specify otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening and reading files are different operations.

A file is opened as a first step in reading from it or writing to it. By default, the `open()` call accesses the file in read mode. Specifying `'r'` as the second argument is just explicitly doing the same thing. (Specifying `'w'` opens the file in write mode.)

Once the file is open, it can be read in one big chunk (such as your code does), a line at a time, a byte at a time or more complex schemes using different read operations.

Answer (score 4):

There are three different things here:

1. the mode in which you open the file
2. the operation you perform on the file
3. implicit arguments sent via default parameters

Your statement:

> To my understanding, the second argument 'r' for the open() is essentially telling the system to read the file after opening it

is not quite correct. The `'r'` indicates that you wish to open the file in read mode; it does not read anything in itself. You can also read a file that is opened in other modes, incidentally.

The `open` function takes a mode string with a default value of `'r'`, so omitting this parameter yields the same thing.