# Remove repeated words in a file with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpu-word

I have a text file with multiple words repeated.
I need every word to appear only once.

**follow the code I'm trying to develop**

```
import  codecs

 wordList = codecs.open('Arquivo.txt' , 'r')
 wordList2 = codecs.open('Arquivo2.txt', 'w')

for x in range(len(wordList)) :
    for y in range(x + 1, len(wordList ) ):
        if wordList[x] == wordList[y]:
            wordList2.append(wordList[x] )
        for y in wordList2:
            wordList.remove(y)
```

**Erro**

```
    wordList2 = codecs.open('File2.txt', 'w').readline()
IOError: File not open for reading
```

Comment: You opened a file, but you never read from it. Also, you cannot append to open files.

Comment: I would try to iterate in each line,  since wordList is not a string therefore has no "length". I would try to separate each line in words, create a list with such words and remove the duplicates and then rewrite the lists in a new file.

Comment: understood. @PySerialKiller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purpose of including 'r' in the open() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375864/purpose-of-including-r-in-the-open-function)

Comment: Please do not edit your original code because when other readers view this, the answers do not directly address the question

Comment: Right, I'm back.

Comment: yeah that's good :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to try this. It will make `wordList` a list instead of a file object. Do it similarly with wordList2 also.

`.strip()` will remove the newline characters.

```
wordList =[line.strip() for line in codecs.open('File.txt' , 'r').readlines()]
```

Edit: Here's the full code I hope it works for you

```
import  codecs

wordList = [line.strip() for line in codecs.open('File.txt' , 'r').readlines()]
wordList2 = [line.strip() for line in codecs.open('File2.txt', 'r').readlines()]
for x in range(len(wordList)) :
    for y in range(x + 1, len(wordList ) ):
        if wordList[x] == wordList[y]:
            wordList2.append(wordList[x])
        for y in wordList2:
            wordList.remove(y)

# assuming the code above is working
# now write your updated contents
with open('outfile1.txt','w') as outfile1:
    for word in wordList:
        outfile1.write(word + '\n')

with open('outfile2.txt','w') as outfile2:
    for word in wordList2:
        outfile2.write(word + '\n')
```

Edit 2: If you want to use a dictionary instead of a list (because dictionary takes O(1) time complexity for a lookup, as opposed to brute forcing comparison  in two lists for duplicates)

```
wordList = {line.strip():1 for line in codecs.open('File.txt' , 'r').readlines()}
```

where `line.strip()` is your key and `1` is your value.To "remove" the word you can just set it's value to 0 by `wordList[word] = 0`

Comment: can I use this example also to create the second list?

Comment: oh wait may i know why is the `wordList2` in write mode instead of read? If im not wrong `readlines()` only applies for files in read mode

Comment: I tried rewriting the unique words in another file.

Comment: hmm what i suggest is that you also make `wordList2` a list. After comparing and removing all the duplicates, then you write the contents of `wordList2` to a file. I'll edit and update the answers and see if it works for you

Comment: or maybe you can use a dictionary instead of a list. will try to come up with a code